# Can interactions be compared against main effects in generalized additive models (GAMs)?

Tags: r, regression, interaction, nonlinear-regression, generalized-additive-model

##### Introduction and Model

I recently had a reviewer ask what the strength of my GAM interactions were compared to my main effects. This was in reference to some predicted probability plots I created. To emulate what I mean, I have created what I'm talking about with data from the `gamair` package using `mgcv`.

```
#### Libraries and Data ####
library(mgcv)
library(gamair)
library(itsadug)
data("wesdr")

#### Fit Model ####
fit <- gam(
  ret 
  ~ s(dur, bs = "cr")
  + s(bmi, bs = "cr")
  + ti(dur,bmi, bs = "cr"),
  method = "REML",
  family = binomial,
  data = wesdr
)

#### Plot Main Effects ####
par(mfrow=c(1,2))

plot(fit,
     select=1,
     trans=plogis,
     shift=coef(fit)[1])

plot(fit,
     select=2,
     trans=plogis,
     shift=coef(fit)[1])

#### Plot Interactions ####
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
fvisgam(fit,
        view = c("dur","bmi"),
        transform = plogis)
```

This creates two sets of plots, the main effects:

[image]

And their interaction:

[image]

##### My Interpretation

Now my model isn't exactly like this, but it's semi-comparable (my interaction has a more linear divide between the contour colors compared to this model). To me, it appears that both main effects seem to have influence on the outcome, but their "strength" can't really be weighed other than very specific predictions. For example, `dur` seems to have a pronounced effect from 0 to 30 (particularly around 10 dur), but becomes increasingly inaccurate with larger values.

For the interaction, it seems that the the red boundary of this plot has the most predictive power (which seems quite strong from what I observe), followed by the weird "red bubble" in the bottom left caused by the bends in the main effects. However, can the main effects and interaction here be directly compared? For me, it seems the interaction in some cases has stronger predictive power (with some regions predicting a 90% chance of retinopathy), whereas this seems to vary in other cases. Because this can be considered on a case-by-case basis, I don't really know if they can be directly compared in this way.

Comment: You need to define "strength of interaction". Anyway, what is obviously of interest here is the local maximum ("weird red bubble") at dur = 10 and bmi = 25. You see that the value of the interaction smoother in this region is roughly the same magnitude as the values of the main effects. The plot of the interaction smoother does not show "predictive power". The "red boundary" is probably the most uncertain region because it is at the edge of your data coverage. You should add an indicator of observations to the plot.

Comment: *The "red boundary" is probably the most uncertain region because it is at the edge of your data coverage. You should add an indicator of observations to the plot.*---I should note that my own data covers the entire contour plot and doesn't have this white zone in the corner. But what do you mean indicator of observations? Do you mean plotted raw data on the contour plot? I think in my case that may be *less* helpful because my models have thousands of observations and it is hard to meaningfully tell what's what.

Comment: I also want to note that the "strength of interaction" is their wording and why I'm a bit hesitant to say with certainty what this all means.

Comment: I mean add indicators of observations like the rugs in the plots of the main effects. In the plot of the interaction smoother these would need to be points. See the `rug` parameter in `plot.gam`. You are intersted in how well your data covers the plot area. It might be useful to plot the width of the confidence interval for the interaction smoother. `plot.gam` also offers options for depicting the uncertainty.

Comment: I think a plot like this communicates the 'strength of interaction' better than any metric would.

Comment: This might help with interpreting what the "meain effects" smooths represent in this kind of decomposed model. https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/432684/1390

Comment: I am in agreement @mkt. I'm trying to find a reasonable response to this review, but perhaps there isn't one beyond pointing again at the plots. @Roland I also have rugs in my original plots, but as I alluded to previously, the plotted values on the interaction plot are so dense that you really can't make heads or tails of it. It's literally just a sea of black dots when I use functions like `draw` in `gratia`, so it wouldn't really be that valuable in my opinion.

Comment: @GavinSimpson thanks for that explanation from that answer. So basically I just should just shake my plot at them and tell them it's good enough?

Comment: @ShawnHemelstrand FYI: turn off the rug plot with `draw()` with `rug = FALSE`. You probably should be excluding (setting to `NA`) any regions of that `ti()` space that are some way from the support for the data - so consider that if you are using exactly this approach with your own data. I would personally fit this as a `te()` once I'd decided that the interaction was significant. Then you can focus on the estimated surface; the output from `fvisgam()` is not showing the interaction (the `ti()`) it's showing the full estimated surface.

Comment: *Then you can focus on the estimated surface; the output from fvisgam() is not showing the interaction (the ti()) it's showing the full estimates surface. *--- I'm confused now. Originally I coded this as above aka `s(x)+s(z)+ti(x,z)` to include the main effect and interaction like specified here: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/mgcv/html/smooth.terms.html. How would I plot the interaction if this isn't the correct way?

Comment: `s(x)+s(z)+ti(x,z)` is the same model as `te(x,z)`, except that the latter has *fewer* smoothing parameters to estimate. I would focus my visualisation on the whole tensor product (which fvisgam is showing) fitted with `te()`. I really wouldn't know how to interpret a just plotting  the `ti()` term (plus the constant) backtransformed to the probability scale. If you want to, you could also fit the main effects only model and plot that and visualise the bivariate (non-interactive) surface alongside the fitted surface from a the `te()` model.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm understanding correctly, but from what you say I must model `te()` alone (without the s functions) in another model solely to get the right interaction plot in `fvisgam`? I'm lost on the purpose of this plot if you have to estimate an entirely separate model for what should be the same thing. I previously avoided the `te()` coding because I wanted to make sure I included main and interaction effects explicitly.

Comment: I think something may be getting lost in translation because the plot I have now (using just `te`) makes zero sense compared to the one I had previously.

Comment: `fvisgam` is showing the result of predicting from your model at a grid of values over `dur` and `bmi`. It isn't showing the `ti()` smooth or a backtransformed version of `ti()`. It is giving you $\hat{y}_i = g^{-1}(\beta_0 + f_1(\texttt{dur}_i) + f_2(\texttt{bmi}_i) + f_3^{*}(\texttt{dur}_i, \texttt{bmi}_i))$ as you have two variables in the model. So no, I'm not telling you to use `te()` to get the right `fvisgam()` output. I'm saying that the plot it creates isn't the pure  interaction (it's not the `ti()` smooth), but it is the same as you would get if you'd used `te()`...

Comment: The `te()` *does* include the main effects and interaction explicitly, that's the entire definition of what a tensor product smooth does. The issues with `te()` is the main effects and the interaction are all bound up in the single surface - you have no way to test if the purse interaction effect is need, or whether an additive model of just the main effects is sufficient. From your comments etc, you seem to imply that `fvisgam()` is plotting the `ti()` term - it's not.

Comment: Okay sorry that makes sense now. I think I just misread what you were trying to say there originally, but your follow up comment makes that clear now. Thanks again Gavin.